# How to animate an element defined inside another data template by triggering the animation from another data template

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, storyboard, custom-controls

So I am making a custom control and in my control template I have two `ItemsControl`s. I would like to animate a user control (change opacity) inside a data template for a mouse enter/leave event triggered from a `Stackpanel` defined in another `ItemsControl`'s data template. However, since Storyboard requires a TargetName, I cannot access the user control using this way. What can I do to achieve this?

Sample code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type pie:PieChartControl}">

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type pie:PieChartControl}">

                <Grid>

                    <ItemsControl
                        ItemsSource="{Binding slices, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                        >
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                                <Grid ... />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>

                                <pie:Slice
                                    Opacity="{Binding opacity}"
                                    x:Name="TheSlice">
                                </pie:Slice>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>

                    <Grid
                        DataContext="{TemplateBinding DataContext}"
                        >
                        <ItemsControl
                            ItemsSource="{Binding slices, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">

                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>

                                    <Grid>
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <StackPanel.Triggers>
                                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TheSlice"
                                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                                                                    To="0.5"/>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                                </EventTrigger>
                                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TheSlice"
                                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                                    To="1"/>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                                </EventTrigger>

                                            </StackPanel.Triggers>

                                            <Rectangle ... />

                                            <TextBlock ... />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can come up with for this problem was to go back to the view models. The element that triggers the animation binds to a property in its DataContext and the setter for that property than provides the animation for a property (in this case opacity) for the element located in another data template. The property will of course have to be bound to a property of the animated element. I was lucky to have the same datacontext for both elements but if thats not the case, then I think that can be achieved by DataContext Proxy class implemented from a Freezable or other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a heads up, I don't think `ItemsControl` will work here very easily because it and it's Items have no knowledge of what item the mouse is currently over since they are non-selectable.

Although it doesn't answer your question, I think you will want to look at [Selector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector(v=vs.110).aspx) and use it or one of its child classes like `ListBox`.  Notice in [`ListBoxItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem(v=vs.110).aspx) (which every item in `ListBox` is), it has a `IsMouseOver`.  What that being the case, you can much more easily have your `ListBoxItem` control template do something like:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Opacity"
                Value="0.5" />
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: Hi, but this doesnt solve the problem right? I mean the source of trigger should need something to locate the element to be animated.